# Url Amigavel com Mysql

Tags: php

estou construindo um site que puxa ids do banco de dados e faz a pagina do post, porém quando ele faz a requisição a url fica como id assim:

```
http://www.meusite.com.br/posts.php?id=2
```

Queria que em vez de mostrar o id, mostrasse o Titulo da postagem que eu pego no banco de dados, por exemplo, www.meusite.com.br/Como_Criar_URls_amigaveis sem necessidade de aparecer o posts.php?id, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente reconstruir o sistema da mais trabalho, mudei o caminho, utilizando Wordpress agora.

Comment: Ainda assim seria interessante votares e aceitar a resposta que melhor solucionava o problema...

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, o que você diz que é mostrar o ID, na verdade não é bem assim, a sua url representa um arquivo no seu servidor, e o ID representa um parâmetro passado para essa página. Quando você aperta o ENTER na barra do seu navegador, ele está realizando uma requisição HTTP GET ao seu servidor, passando esse parametro ID.

Nessa página, provavelmente existe um código assim:

```
Select * from Posts where postID = $_GET["ID"]
```

Ou seja, "Traga o POST aonde o ID é igual ao Parâmetro passado na requisição"

Imagine se você trocasse o parâmetro ID por TituloPost, seu código provavelmente ficaria assim:

```
Select * from Posts where titPost = $_GET["TituloPost"]
```

Agora pense comigo, você cria um botão em uma certa parte de seu site, que redireciona para esse seu post, por exemplo, quando alguem clica em um link, é aberto o endereço;

http://www.seublog.com.br/posts.php?tituloPost=ComoCriarVariosLinkAmigavel

Mas digamos que você edite o título do post para

"ComoCriarLinkAmigavel"

Você teria um problema, pois o botão de redirecionamento está definido com o parametro tituloPost = "ComoCriarVariosLinkAmigavel".

Então a manutenibilidade do seu site fica extremamente baixa.

Outra situação seria mais de um post ter o mesmo título, o que quebraria o funcionamento do site, aonde cada página mostra um post.

Ou seja, existem diversas situações que tornam essa prática inviável.

**É possível criar Links amigáveis?**

Sim, é possível criar links mais amigáveis, no entanto, é totalmente recomendado o uso do ID como parâmetro, pois o ID além de ser único, representa um valor seguro de mudanças, ou seja, você pode editar o seu post, título, tags, que o ID vai continuar o mesmo.

Comment: Entendi então, o correto seria eu criar um sql que procura com base no numero da id e no nome do post, porém, depois disso, como coloco meu htacces?

Comment: **1** A 'manutenibilidade' não esta ligada ao sistema de url amigável, isso é extremamente simples de fazer. **2** `totalmente recomendado o uso do ID como parâmetro` - totalmente equivocado.

Comment: Por favor escreva sua resposta

Comment: @FernandoMedeiros, ja tenho varias sobre o tema

Answer (score 2):

O que você descreve é um desejo que muita gente tem ao criar um site. A resposta do Fernando Medeiros é bastante útil e simples, basicamente falando **use o ID, não se preocupe**.

Eu concordo com isso, e acho que, no caso de *posts*, o `ID` no URL é prática e fácil.

Mas, como que as outras pessoas fazem? Como vários sites conseguem ter URLs bem prátcias e amgiáveis, mas também que conseguem mantê-los de forma fácil, sobrepujando os riscos que o Fernando menciunou? <sub>E, de verdade, são incomodações graves que podem custar muito!</sub>

Um desenvolvedor comum como eu usa um *framework* já estabelecido. No caso de *posts* e PHP e MySql, existe o framework de [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org). O Wordpress consegue manter seus URLs amigávels utilizando o banco de dados, e um algortimo de "achar" o URL mais próximo, caso não seja um url exato.

Basicamente, minha "resposta" seria, não tenta reinventar a roda<sup>†</sup>, ou seja não tenta criar tudo do zero, mas sim, usa um framework que já resolveu todos esses problemas.

<sub>† Não sei se essa expressão que temos em inglês dá o mesmo no português :P</sub>

Comment: O wordpress pode ser uma boa saída mesmo

Comment: Com certeza, fui tentar reinventar a roda pensando que era fácil, da trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples seria alterar seu `.htaccess` para algo do tipo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^post/([0-9]+)/(.*)?$   posts.php?id=$1   [NC,L]

// OBS: talvez precise alterar algum detalhe
```

Assim, a url:

```
http://www.meusite.com.br/post/22/titulo-do-post
http://www.meusite.com.br/post/22/titulo-do-post-editado
```

Seriam interpretadas como:

```
http://www.meusite.com.br/posts.php?id=22
```

Ou seja, o título seria usado para deixar o url amigável e melhorar o SEO. No fundo o que importaria para exibição correta seria o ID. Isso permite que você altere o título do post sem quebrar os links com título antigo.

Cabe a você gerar as urls na sua aplicação, lembrando de gerar esse **slug** do título do posts.

```
slug('Título do post') = titulo-do-post
```